# Box API for Android (v1) not working anymore?

Tags: android, box-api

This is the old api (v1)
https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk
this is the new api (v2)
https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk-v2

but my app was using the old api (v1), it works fine until 1-2 months ago
I want to know if v1 is not supported anymore?
I am getting following errors:

```
05-05 16:52:57.806: W/System.err(24640): [DEBUG] GbaRequest - GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
05-05 16:52:57.806: W/System.err(24640): [DEBUG] NafRequest - NafRequest: NafRequest constructor===useragent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
```

when using following codes

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BoxAuthentication.class);
intent.putExtra("API_KEY", Constants.API_KEY); // API_KEY is required
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTH_REQUEST_CODE_BOX);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V1 support ended December 15th 2013.

So your statement is correct: V1 is not supported anymore.

Box gave everyone about 18 months from first announcement, including giving an extra couple months past the December date to any heavily used app to move off V1.  We also made as much noise about it in developer communities (including Stack Overflow) as we felt was reasonable.

Communication included blog posts, emails to application owners, and mentions in events like BoxWorks and BoxDev.

Feel free to reach out to Box for help at api@box.com and they'll do what they can to guide you through converting your application.  Most developers are able to convert in a few days.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I wasn't active in box forum or SO's box-api tag. As far as I remembered, my app still works fine until late February.  
I will take my time to port my app to V2. Thanks again =)